# Can I use the facebook credentials to for users to access my site?

Tags: facebook, authentication, openid, identity-management

I'm starting to work on a site that will be strongly connected to a corresponding [Facebook](http://facebook.com) app. I want the contents to be free for all to view, but only registered users will be able to edit it (quite similar to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), actually).

Since I think that most of my users will be logged in to facebook, I would really like to use their facebook credentials as to login to my site - the same way Open-Id registration works here.

Can this be done?

Thanks,

Udi Pasmon

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the things provided by [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php).  There is a [wiki full of documentation](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect#Authorizing_Users) - start at ["Authenticating Users with Facebook Connect"](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect/Authentication_and_Authorization).