# ISpRecoGrammar::IsPronounceable in PHP?

Tags: php, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech

I was trying to track down something that could test a string for "Pronounceability" and though I actually doubt there's anything that might be freely available.

I was actually a bit surprised to find that Microsoft has a library.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718902(VS.85).aspx

This got me thinking, maybe it does exist elsewhere or maybe there's some reasonable combination of soundex+foo that I might be able to put together that would award either a BOOL or a "% RATING" that might help me determine if a generated string is pronounceable.

How would you tackle the problem?  Difficulty: make it happen on a LAMP system (I'd like my web server to automatically categorize the PINDEX for the words).

EDIT:
oo... found some more cool links.
Cool!   :)

http://www.addedbytes.com/code/flesch-kincaid-function/

[how to check if a string looks randomized, or human generated and pronouncable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164186/)

EDIT2:

oh my!  there is a google code project available:

http://code.google.com/p/php-text-statistics/

If I do manage to get it working, I'll be sure to follow up with a brief tutorial.

Comment: Cool!   :) 
http://www.addedbytes.com/code/flesch-kincaid-function/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164186/

Comment: Have a look at the inbuilt PHP `soundex()` function: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) You might be able to use that for what you're looking for